# Kendo Chart PDF/Image Export- Special characters html decode issue

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

My code displays the Kendochart correctly. But when I export(pdf/image) the chart, the < and > symbol is not getting decoded. Displays as `&lt;` and `&gt;` . Please see the screenshot of the PDF.

This is the code:

```
$(document).delegate(".btnpdf", "click", function() {
  var chart = $("#chart").getKendoChart();
  chart.exportPDF({
    paperSize: "A5",
    landscape: true
  }).done(function(data) {
    kendo.saveAs({
      dataURI: data,
      fileName: "chart.pdf"
    });
  });
});
```

[image: legend PDF]

Comment: Can you show your series data and describe how it is retrieved ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the exporter does not decode the series names, you will have to do it yourself.

```
function decode (encoded) {
    return $.parseHTML(encoded)[0].textContent;
}

$(document).delegate(".btnpdf","click",function() {
       var chart = $("#chart").getKendoChart();

       // decode each series name
       chart.options.series.forEach(function(item){
            item.name = decode(item.name);
       });
       chart.refresh();


       chart.exportPDF({ paperSize: "A5", landscape: true }).done(function(data) {
        kendo.saveAs( 
        ...
```